# What's the proper way to require in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, require, electron

I'm just getting started with Node.js and Electron, and I've seen various ways both in the documentation and in example code on how to require modules. Specifically, I am trying to follow [this](https://medium.com/developers-writing/building-a-desktop-application-with-electron-204203eeb658#.86gynone0) tutorial. In this particular example, I think I am requiring `app` which is in `electron`.

1) In the tutorial, it has you do:

```
var app = require('app')
```

2) In the [electron-quick-start](https://github.com/electron/electron-quick-start) example, which is provided by Electron to help you get started, they have you do:

```
const electron = require('electron')
const app = electron.app
```

3) In [Electron documentation](http://electron.atom.io/docs/api/app/), they use:

```
const {app} = require('electron')
```

4) In an [Electron boilerplate program](https://github.com/szwacz/electron-boilerplate/blob/master/src/app.js), I found:

```
import { remote } from 'electron'
var app = remote.app
```

What is going on here? I have mostly seen #1 around the Internet, and it seems that `var` and `const` can be essentially interchanged because you don't modify these modules. What I'm failing to understand is if `app` is in `electron`, then why can #1 directly require it (rather than something like `require('electron.app')`)?. I am further confused because #4 seems to imply app is actually in `electron.remote`. Secondly, is #3 preferred because it's used in the documentation? Or is #4 preferred? The comment in the program for #4 says "Use new ES6 modules syntax for everything". Does this mean this is the future of JavaScript? And of course, I would like to know if these are just syntactic differences or if they actually affect how the program is run.

Comment: IMHO just use `var http = require('http')`. `var` vs `const` is up to you.

Comment: in some cases i've had problems using just  `var` for my main.js file for electron. the one that didn't give me problems was  `const {app} = require('electron')`. The only diference is they where in different standars of typing

Comment: I would avoid using `var` entirely if you have `const` and `let` available. See the example [here](http://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-var)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `#1` no longer works in Electron v1.0+.
- `#2` and `#3` are equivalent, `#3` just uses a [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment).
- `#4` uses [ES6 module import](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/import) syntax which NodeJS doesn't handle natively yet, so it only works if you transpile your code with Babel, or TypeScript, or some other transpiler that can transform those `import` statements to `require` statements.

Comment: Thank you! No wonder I was having trouble using #1, I didn't realize it didn't work anymore.