# Error when running "npm start"?

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I have started with electron today and followed a guide to create a simple application browser window and I ran npm start in the command window and it displayed a lot of errors after I had entered it, I have posted the information below and my code.

Console error:

```
C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\electron>npm start

> breef@1.0.0 start C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\electron
> node index.js

module.js:471
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'app'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\electron\index.js:1:73)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)

npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.14393
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"
npm ERR! node v6.9.2
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.9
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! breef@1.0.0 start: `node index.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the breef@1.0.0 start script 'node index.js'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the breef package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node index.js
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs breef
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls breef
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\electron\npm-debug.log
```

Here is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "breef",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "A simple chat application.",
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "electron": "^1.4.12"
  },
  "devDependencies": {},
  "scripts": {
    "test": "breeftestcmd",
    "start": "node index.js"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "breef"
  ],
  "author": "Sage & Sh4wn",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

Here is my index.js:

```
var app = require("app")
var browserWindow = require("browser-window")

app.on('ready', function() {
    var mainWindow = new browserWindow({
        width: 800,
        height: 600
    })

    mainWindow.loadUrl('http://google.com');
})
```

Comment: Is `app` a module within `node_modules` or another file within your project? To require your project's own modules, [the path should start with `/`, `./`, or `../`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v7.x/docs/api/modules.html#modules_file_modules) – e.g. `require("./app")`. "*Without a leading '/', './', or '../' to indicate a file, the module must either be a core module or is loaded from a node_modules folder.*"

Answer (score 0):

If app is a module, it's missing in your package.json. If not, you should use a path to require it

```
var app = require('./app');
```

Answer (score 0):

The guide you followed is out of date, as of Electron v1.0.0 the way built-in Electron modules are imported has changed. This is the correct way:

```
const {app, BrowserWindow} = require("electron")
```

You may also find it beneficial to read the previous question that covered this topic: [What's the proper way to require in Node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39257088/whats-the-proper-way-to-require-in-node-js)